# Textbattles KoTH

Tags: string, grid, king-of-the-hill

## Textbattles

---

Textbattles is is strategy game about, well, text.
It consists of a 10x10 grid, where each player has a position on the grid. When it is a player's turn, they can decide whether to move a step in any direction on the grid, or just stay where they are.

If a player moves into another player's spot, they are both put in a battle with each other. They both will generate a piece of text. After generating it, they get a "penalty" stored, which = time in nanoseconds to generate / 80000. Then, each player sends the first *n* characters of their text to eachother, where *n* is the penalty. After that, both player have two choices:
1. Guess the other player's text, using the portion given to them.
2. Surrender (this can also be done after trying to guess multiple times)
Surrendering is an instant elimination from the game, guessing before the other player eliminates the other player.

To participate in the challenge you will have to code your player, here is how your code should look in **Java**:

```
public class MyPlayer extends Player {
    @Override
    public Move move() {
        return Move.LEFT, Move.RIGHT, Move.UP, Move.DOWN, or Move.NONE
    }
    @Override
    public void guess(String clue, Checker checker) {
        if(checker.guess("I think this is the right one!")) {
            // Got it right!
            return;
        }
        checker.surrender();
    }
    @Override
    public String generate(Deducter ded) {
        ded.use(); // Read below
        return "SecretCode404";
    }
    // Other methods you have access to: getGrid: a 2d-array of booleans, each element being true if there is a player there,
                                         getRandom: a java.util.Random object to generate random numbers, by the rules of this challenge, you aren't allowed to use any other random number generator than this one.
}
```

Each time you win a battle, you get a *point*, and the next time you get in to a battle, you have the choice to deduct the amount of points from your penalty as shown above.

---

## FAQ

---

- What stops me from adding the entire Lorem Ipsum to my text?
   Other people can look at your answer and compensate for it by adding Lorem Ipsum too.
- What if none of the two battlers never find eachother's text?
   They will. In most cases anyways, if they don't find it in 5 minutes, it is considered a tie and nobody is eliminated
- What if all players keep avoiding eachother?
    There are random events that teleport players to eachother.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/82385/discussion-on-question-by-firecubez-textbattles-koth).